# Can you have Type Theory without types?

Tags: type-theory

Thinking about Type Theory, we define types such as the natural numbers:

```
zero:Nat
succ(n:Nat):Nat
```

But I thought that this might be equivalent to having just 2 types: Atomic and True . Then one might have:

```
zero:Atomic
isNat(zero):True
Implies(isNat(n),isNat(succ(n))):True
```

i.e. more or less replace all types **T** with functions **isT**(..). Everything else which isn't a function is an atom. Or one could do away with atoms too and have them as functions with no arguments. Is this equivalent or would such a scheme reintroduce Russell's Paradox that type theory was designed to avoid?

A dependent type such as Even n would be defined as a function definition instead of a type declaration:

```
Even = n => ( a=> isNat(a) && 2*a==n )
```

Then a proof that 6 is even is just Even(6)(3) with 3 supplying the proof (if I have that idea right).

Comment: This seems cumbersome. How will you handle functions that are only defined on natural numbers, for example?

Comment: isNat(a)->isNat(b)->isNat(plus(a,b)) for example. Not sure if dependent types would be translated though

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you assume $\texttt{zero} : \texttt{Atomic}$ and $\texttt{succ} : \texttt{Atomic} \to \texttt{Atomic}$, so you are essentially already asumming a type of natural numbers.

It might also make more sense to name your second type $\texttt{Prop}$ of propositions rather than $\texttt{True}$.